# How to go up a directory from current directory with GetPrivateProfileString()

Tags: c++, ini

I am trying to read auth details for my program from a ini file using `GetPrivateProfileString`. I would like to go up a `directory/Folder/File.ini`) but don't know how to do so

I have tried `GetFullPathName()`

```cpp
void ini {


std::string iniPath = "/Ice/Ice.ini";
    LPWSTR inipath = A2W_EX(iniPath.c_str(), iniPath.length());



    DWORD IniPath = std::strtoul(iniPath.c_str(), NULL, 16);


    std::string playerUsername;

    std::string playerPassword;

    TCHAR iniauthChar[32];



    playerUsername = GetPrivateProfileString(authheader, authuser, 0, iniauthChar, 256, inipath);
    playerPassword = GetPrivateProfileString(authheader, authpass, 0, iniauthChar, 256, inipath);



}
```

and here is my ini file located a directory above

```
[AUTH]
Username=
Password=
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path

Comment: @TedLyngmo After including filesystem and adding ```namespace fs = std::filesystem; ``` filesystem is not a member of std

Comment: Are you compiling using the `C++17` language option? If you do `namespace fs = std::filesystem;` you can then use `fs::path` or `std::filesystem::path` etc.

Comment: I don't know I have checked under ```properties->C/C++->Language``` and don't see ```C++ Language Standard``` However I can tell you i'm using SDK ```Windows 8.1``` and build tools ```v140``` Those two things I cannot change.

Comment: I have done some testing with the ini file. I have loaded it using the path. and it returns NULL as the result

Comment: @TedLyngmo and 73areo: While C++17 has std::filesystem, visual studio 2017 does not fully implement it. So if you use VS2017 you should use std::experimental::filesystem.

Comment: @user1810087 Yeah, I assumed VS2019. 73areo, can you tag the question with the visual-studio version you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\\` instead of `/` for directory paths on Windows.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LPWSTR fn = L"Ice\\Ice.ini";

    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];      
    GetFullPathNameW(fn, MAX_PATH, buf, NULL);

    std::wcout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

Or with ANSI strings:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    LPSTR fn = "Ice\\Ice.ini";

    char buf[MAX_PATH];     
    GetFullPathNameA(fn, MAX_PATH, buf, NULL);

    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Most library functions in windows do support slash as directory seperator.